# How to keep IONIC app running after closing

Tags: ionic-framework, service, task

I've created a reminder app with local notifications.
How do I keep the app working as service after closing it? (something similar to android alarm clock)

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: what service you want to keep Active? you can use Background Mode or Local Notification schedule!

Comment: I've tested background mode, but I need to keep the app running after i close it (the same as in the clock app that comes with android, in which you define an alarm and then you close the app... but the "service" keeps running)

Comment: Background it is when you open another program and the application goes in background mode. But I'm asking about of totally closing the app... It should work as a service

Comment: what service you want t keep running? what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: When the user closes the app I need to keep it running in order to send local notifications. It's the same than the clock application that comes with android phones. When you close it, it keeps running (as a service or something similar) so it can trigger alarm notifications... I need to do this in IONIC. How can I achieve this?

Comment: you can use this plugin : https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/local-notifications

Comment: The question is not about local notifications. That is something I already resolved.
I am asking about installing a IONIC application as a service that keeps running without any kind of interface with the user.

Answer (score 0):

Try **services**. You need to learn **android native at minimal level** to achieve your specifications.
https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services
I also have the same requirement of waking up app on receiving notifications. **So I wrote a service** and added in **AndroidManifest.xml.**